# Android - ¿Como acceder al contenido de un telefono que no funciona?

Tags: android

Tengo un telefono con sistema operativo Android y tengo un terrible inconveniente...

Lo que pasa es que despues de bajar aplicaciones y usarlo por un buen tiempo, dejo de funcionar correctamente, se traba cuando se reinicia, y cuando entra al sistema operativo despues de poner la contraseña se traba, no funcionan los gestos, ni el touch, simplemente esta trabado, despues de unos segs se reinicia solo y vuelve a pasar lo mismo.

Hay alguna manera de recuperar los archivos guardados en la memoria interna del telefono?

Nota:

- No esta activada la opcion de desarrollador
- La pc no lo detecta cuando esta encendido
- Tengo que quitarle la bateria cada vez que quiero reiniciarlo bien
- Si puede entrar al menu de recovery

Answer (score 1):

> Hay alguna manera de recuperar los archivos guardados en la memoria
>   interna del telefono?

No, acceder a la memoria interna del télefono es casi imposible si no tienes configurado tu telefono con permisos de **Root**.

Root es equivalente a tener los máximos privilegios posibles en tu teléfono.

Te recomiendo este excelente articulo: [Que significa ser Root en Android](https://www.taringa.net/post/info/13770035/Que-significa-ser-root-en-android.html)

---

Aunque tuvieras activadas las opciones de desarrollador y USB debugging, unicamente podrias accesar a el almacenamiento externo si no tienes tu telefono configurado como root.

Answer (score 1):

Respecto a **recuperar** datos de algún dispositivo (*en este caso un móvil*), puedes utilizar

> herramientas forenses

, con ellas puedes hacer una imagen del móvil y montarlo en otra app. Te dejo este enlace para que te des cuenta de algunas.

http://conexioninversa.blogspot.com/2013/09/forensics-powertools-listado-de.html

Answer (score 0):

Puedes cambiarle el Recovery por uno modificado como (CWM or TWRP), el cual te permitira montar la SD interna del celular y poder extraer la informacion de ahi.